# mp3 files not supported by phonon

Tags: phonon

I am using Qt SDK 4.6 for developing a simple music player on windows XP.
I have checked available mime types supported by phonon and according to it my phonon supports mp3 files
Yet as i try to play an audio file of .mp3 format using my music player mediaObject moves in Error State and the error i get is 
Fatal Error : No combination of filters could be found to render the stream
Secondly, I want to know how can i provide support for other audio files which are not currently supported by phonon like as .ogg file.
Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Phonon is just an abstraction layer over a media player backend.  Check the overview [here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/phonon-overview.html) and look for the Backends section.

You need to install mp3 codecs for your target backend.  If you're on Windows, this is making sure you have mp3 playback in DirectShow/DirectX.  Your error implies that you don't have any DirectShow filters for mp3